# Unhandled exception in Silverlight : System.Exception

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, exception, unhandled-exception, mmppf

I am using SMF player for online video streaming in my project.
Randomly application crashes. (Sometime Application runs for 60 hr, sometimes apln crashes in 2 hr)
I have added the unhandled exception handler to main class.

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;         
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But during exception, I am only getting the following information, No stacktrace info.

> UnhandledException of type System.Exception, Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which versions are you using (MMPPF version + SL plugin + SL SDK)?

Comment: I'm still having similar crashes since Silverlight 5. I'm afraid we'll have to wait on MS to publish an update to the plugin/SDK to fix the multiple issues with multimedia content (see DRM mess).

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same random errors with Smooth Streaming Media Element (SL4, SSME 1.5 - > but I got it also with SL5)

If I call stacktrace on application error handeling, then the app crashes.

Its some nasty error in my productive app.

Best workaround I found for that was to bring the app up with JS, when it comes non-responsive (run some timer in SL, update some timestamp on HTML, make a reaload, if timestamp is older than 10 seconds or so) ..